# Generic tree with UNIQUE generic nodes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, translation, type-inference

### Problem description

I have a generic tree with generic nodes. You can think about it like it is a extended router config with multi-level children elements.

The catch is, that each node can have other generic type that its parent (more details - [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-f6ApJ7EFK26fDoiKbS2UueWKwMZrNaT0RjpQGRpmVyhWJwSAURBAHwggEYQOuADhAxMyOrNC-DDX9A2E0DpcdBg7z42lBHMFjQ2QRQuF+1EhTTJWLhZKMtKCYhEQK0AREy9VZ7vUmsY8A1IJr25xAAJIYcOfKOIgEQkeg49FnKkUsbrc74CVn8-lCP983bZNi3Yb8IE3P5t13QNAF4QQBWEEAFhBAAYQQAmEAQxskKgQB+EBrQBBEEAIRBAGkQFtPjArFO0RHtZwHL40B8MA0kRe8sUQHE8QJL8uk5UhuWHflSAXCV9igMYoBsaYAGUACYAGY5LkqYeHAaATBXOl03LbMbRNABuQ8xGIYpKg5eA8DwYhyFIeBIicNA7HUqRxRFNdi2g394P01UjK9McmQnagpw5S8BzwUSRWXRdtKgEA0HYABZfwAGl6kdChD1aT5T0DORwqiLRC0fP5nyBV9E19ItU1ueLEpSkB0q8QMEvYXx-Cgc5PBbQsOhLOq2sa5rPEDDCa0AdhBAB4QGtADYQBCaygDDSKgCaELQwAuEBrKbSImCisSolMoi7JFXPooqWFM4B2MjLj8VqzoZz7AcoslCSpNsHh5KUlTphczTYqlTyYOAOD-0y8h-MaEyzLQCyrJsuyHLsJy4gBsSgaGtKMt8igocEZ1x2oIA)).

So when node has children, the problem is lying in typing its nodes generics.

### Code

```
type ReactNode = string



type languageTag = 'en' | 'ru'/* | 'de' | 'cs' | 'fr' | 'cn' | 'pl' */



// the type below may be the problem
type translations<T extends unknown = unknown> = {
  [key in languageTag]: T
}



interface pageData<T extends unknown = unknown> {
  path: string,
  contentTranslations: translations<T>
  element: ReactNode,
  children?: Array<pageData<T>>
}



const informationPageData: pageData<{ hobbies: string/* , fullName: string, birthDate: string, sex: string, ... */ }> = {
  path: 'information',
  contentTranslations: {
    en: { hobbies: 'hobbies' },
    ru: { hobbies: 'хобби' }
  },
  element: 'profile information'
}



const profilePageData: pageData<{ recentPosts: string }> = {
  path: ':profileId',
  contentTranslations: {
    en: { recentPosts: 'recent posts' },
    ru: { recentPosts: 'недавние посты' }
  },
  element: 'profile component',
  children: [ informationPageData ] // Error
}



const profilesPageData: pageData<{ youMayKnow: string }> = {
  path: '/profiles',
  contentTranslations: {
    en: { youMayKnow: 'you may know' },
    ru: { youMayKnow: 'возможно вы знакомы' }
  },
  element: 'profiles list',
  children: [ profilePageData ] // Error
}
```

### Questions

Where should I get those types from?

The goal is to make it as much DRY as it could be. Maybe with type inferring?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-f6ApJ7EFK26fDoiKbS2UueWKwMZrNaT0RjpQGRpmVyhWJwSAURBAHwggEYQOuADhAxMyOrNC-DDX9A2E0DpcdBg7z42lBHMFjQ2QRQuF+1EhTTJWLhZKMtKCYhEQK0AREy9VZ7vUmsY8A1IJr25xAAJIYcOfKOIgEQkeg49FnKkUsbrc74CVn8-lCP983bZNi3Yb8IE3P5t13QNAF4QQBWEEAFhBAAYQQAmEAQxskKgQB+EBrQBBEEAIRBAGkQFtPjArFO0RHtZwHL40B8MA0kRe8sUQHE8QJL8uk5UhuWHflSAXCV9igMYoBsaYAGUACYAGY5LkqYeHAaATBXOl03LbMbRNABuQ8xGIYpKg5eA8DwYhyFIeBIicNA7HUqRxRFNdi2g394P01UjK9McmQnagpw5S8BzwUSRWXRdtKgEA0HYABZfwAGl6kdChD1aT5T0DORwqiLRC0fP5nyBV9E19ItU1ueLEpSkB0q8QMEvYXx-Cgc5PBbQsOhLOq2sa5rPEDDCa0AdhBAB4QGtADYQBCaygDDSKgCaELQwAuEBrKbSImCisSolMoi7JFXPooqWFM4B2MjLj8VqzoZz7AcoslCSpNsHh5KUlTphczTYqlTyYOAOD-0y8h-MaEyzLQCyrJsuyHLsJy4gBsSgaGtKMt8igocEZ1x2oIA)

Can I have your help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `pageData` interface is the parent `T` is the same type required by the children. What you want is to open up the generic type to accommodate any record therefor allowing the children to define their own properties.

```
interface pageData<T extends Record<string, string>> {
  path: string,
  contentTranslations: translations<T>
  element: ReactNode,
  children?: Array<pageData<Record<string, string>>>
}
```

You will still get the strongly typed nature of the component props, but without the inherited restrictions

Comment: Is it possible to have somehow inferred children generic types? For example if i want to recursively iterate over all pageData objects and get their contentTranslations typings?

Comment: @RamoFX No that would defeat the purpose of generics. You would have to hard code all of the types and then you type assertions at runtime like `const isHobby = (translation: any): translation is { hobby: string } => typeof translation.hobby === 'string')`